# Segmentation fault when trying to create an avl tree of strings

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

I come from a Java background and I thought it'd be nice to learn c,for that I decided to read a data structures book and learn the language syntax as I read it,but now I have a problem,I'm trying to create an avl tree where it's key value will be a string,however when I tried to convert the example in my book examples,which uses int,to char* the complier just shows up segmentation fault error :(
This is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// An AVL tree node
struct node {
    char *key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b);

// A utility function to get height of the tree
int height(struct node *N) {
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return N->height;
}

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
 NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(char *key) {
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = strdup(key);
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->height = 1;  // new node is initially added at leaf
    return (node);
}

// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct node *rightRotate(struct node *y) {
    struct node *x = y->left;
    struct node *T2 = x->right;

    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    // Update heights
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return x;
}

// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct node *leftRotate(struct node *x) {
    struct node *y = x->right;
    struct node *T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    //  Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}

// Get Balance factor of node N
int getBalance(struct node *N) {
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, char *key) {
    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (node == NULL)
        return (newNode(key));

    if (strcmp(key, node->key) < 0)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = max(height(node->left), height(node->right)) + 1;

    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor node to check whether
     this node became unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
        return rightRotate(node);

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
        return leftRotate(node);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key) {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key) {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

// A utility function to print preorder traversal of the tree.
// The function also prints height of every node
void preOrder(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

/* Drier program to test above function*/
int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;

    /* Constructing tree given in the above figure */
    root = insert(root, "10");
    root = insert(root, "20");
    root = insert(root, "30");
    root = insert(root, "40");
    root = insert(root, "50");
    root = insert(root, "25");

    /* The constructed AVL Tree would be
     30
     /  \
         20   40
     /  \     \
       10  25    50
     */

    printf("Pre order traversal of the constructed AVL tree is \n");
    preOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", root->key);` should be `%s`, since `root->key` is a `char *`

Comment: rightRotate does not check nullptr, y->left could be nullptr.

Comment: @bezzi `I come from a Java background and I thought it'd be nice to learn c` But you also tagged your question as `C++`. In C++, there is `std::string` which you should use in place of `char *`. Also, `typedef struct` and specifying the keyword `struct` all over the place (other than the definition of the type) is not needed in C++. In addition, dynamic allocation is usually and preferably done using `new` and `delete` (also with mention that you failed to release any of the memory you allocated. So are you learning C or learning C++?

Comment: Yeah that tag was a mistake,I will delete it,thank you for the tips :D

Comment: Actually doing `#include <string>` won't work in C ...

Comment: Yeah,all that happened because I was playing with c++ strings on the same file before starting the avl problem.Btw is it ok to post the version of the code that works as an answer here,so people who find that question on google can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`strcmp`** beacause you are converting from **`int`** to **`char`**, you can learn a lot more about this topic reading standard books about the great c programming language

Answer (score 1):

When you changed the key type from `int` to `char *`, you correctly changed the insert step to use `strcmp`, but the rebalancing steps still use the `<` operator on strings. This breaks assumptions the code makes about certain nodes being non-NULL. By updating the conditionals for the left-left/left-right/etc cases to also use `strcmp`, the code works as intended.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, you should change `printf` to use `%s` instead of `%d`.

Comment: A comment to go along with the downvote would be nice - I tested the code with my suggested changes, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In `rightRotate()` if `x->right` is `NULL` you need to call `newNode()` to create a node before you do the assignment to T2. I suspect there are other places like this throughout the code.

Comment: This does not fix the root of the problem.